# Deleting files on a remote machine (shared folder) using msbuild

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-4.0, msbuildextensionpack

I want to delete files kept in a shared folder on a remote machine using msbuild. I have googled but couldn't get a proper solution. Please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question: Following code is working.

```
<ItemGroup>
        <ServiceLocation Include="\\ServerName\FolderName\*.*"></ServiceLocation>
      </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="Deploy">
    <Delete Files="@(ServiceLocation)" />
    </Target>
```

Comment: Please mark as "The Answer" so it doesn't keep coming up in unanswered filters on the stackoverflow pages.

Answer (score -1):

try with this one,

```
<Target Name="SomeTarget">

<ItemGroup>
    <FilesToDelete Include="Path\To\Obj\**\*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Delete Files="@(FilesToDelete)" />

</Target>
```

Comment: I am trying to delete only files and on remote machine.